# MySQL foreign key violation 20% of the time

Tags: mysql, go

I have one of those, "it happens sometimes" problems, and I don't know where to begin even.

I have the following database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `group` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_group` (`group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `group` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So, I have a group table, and a person table. The person can only belong to one group, so it has a foreign key called group_id;

If I try to delete a group which has a person referencing to it, I usually get a foreign key error, could not delete group. BUT, sometimes, mysql happily removes the group, leaving me with a person referencing a non-existent group.

- MySQL version is 5.7.10, running the official Docker image
- Tables are InnoDB
- FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS is set to 1

Now, before actually trying to delete a group, I'm running a select on both tables to see their content; maybe that helps.

I have something like this:

```
### Groups ####
id: 1, name: My group!
id: 2, name: Hello!
id: 3, name: Wat!
id: 22, name: My Group!
id: 23, name: My Other Group!
id: 24, name: Completely Different Group!

### People ####
id: 26, group_id: 1
id: 28, group_id: 3
id: 25, group_id: 23
```

Then the DELETE comes in... and I end up with the following:

```
### Groups ####
id: 1, name: My group!
id: 2, name: Hello!
id: 3, name: Wat!
id: 22, name: My Group!
id: 24, name: Completely Different Group!

### People ####
id: 26, group_id: 1
id: 28, group_id: 3
id: 25, group_id: 23
```

The Group with the id: 23 was deleted even though the person:25 is still referencing it.

MySQL logs look like this in both cases (when a foreign key constraint error is thrown, or not):

```
....
114 Query  SELECT id, name FROM group
113 Query  SELECT id, group_id FROM person
114 Prepare        DELETE FROM group WHERE id = ?
114 Execute        DELETE FROM group WHERE id = 23
114 Close stmt
```

As I said already multiple times, this only happens ~20% of the case. I'm using the `go-sql-driver/mysql` to access the database.

Sample code that does all this:

```
getAllGroups := "SELECT id, name FROM group"
getAllUsers  := "SELECT id, group_id FROM person"

rows, err := DB.Query(getAllGroups)
checkErr(err)
defer rows.Close()

// Print all the groups

rows, err = DB.Query(getAllUsers)
checkErr(err)
defer rows.Close()

// Print all the users
// Each group is referenced by a user

query := "DELETE FROM group WHERE id = ?"
_, err = DB.Exec(query, groupID)
// Detect if the deletion failed
if err != nil {
  if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "a foreign key constraint fails") {
    // FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT FAILED
  }
  // SOMETHING ELSE FAILED
}
// EVERYTHING WORKED... even though it shouldn't have
```

Comment: Can you try adding `ON DELETE CASCADE` to your foreign key definition?

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I want the default `ON DELETE RESTRICT` where if something references a row, I shouldn't be able to delete it.